# Javascript Calculation not working properly

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to do a simple calculation of three values:  `a + b * c` but getting wrong total. If `a` is 10 and `b` is 10 it would be 20 multiplied by `c` which is 2.4. I should get 48 as total. Currently getting 2424.

```
function compute() {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  var c = $('#c').val();
  var total = (a + b) * c;
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#a, #b, #c').change(compute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try after parsing the values like:
var total = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)) * parseFloat(c);

Answer (score 1):

**Basic maths : multiplication have precedence over addition.**

So in your code, a is additionned to the result of b*c .

Use :

```
var total = (a + b) * c;
```

Answer (score 1):

`a + b * c`  is being evaluated as `a + (b * c)`

What you need is `(a + b) * c`

**Precedence**: Brackets > Division > Multiplication > Addition > Subtraction

---

In your question, you stated that you get 1024. Getting 1024 is **impossible**. You should get 34. (Check your calculation elsewhere)

```
a + (b * c) = 10 + (10 * 2.4) = 34
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a to b BEFORE multiplying, you'll need to use parentheses.

That's because the multiplication oprator has higher precedence than addition.

(a + b) * c

Comment: Hello mrlucmorin see above code updated.  Now getting 2424?? instead of 48.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function compute() { 
          var a = $('#a').val();
          var b = $('#b').val();
          var c = $('#c').val();
          var total = (parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10)) * parseFloat(c); alert(total);
          $('#total').val(total);
        }

  $('#a, #b, #c').change(compute);

 });
```

### [Check DEMO](http://jsbin.com/otuzur/1/edit)

Answer (score -2):

Your variables are strings. Use parseFloat function.

```
"10" + "10"*"2.4" = "10"+ 24 = "1024"
```

Comment: use parseFloat before making arithmetic operations